# JDBC and Concurrency issues

Tags: java, mysql, database, jdbc, concurrency

I want some advice on some concurrency issues regarding jdbc, i basically need to update a value and then retrieve that value using a update then a select, I'm assuming by turning auto commit off no other transaction can access this table, hence other transactions won't be able to perform update and select queries until this has been committed.

Below is some example code. Do you think this will work and does any one else have a better solution to implementing this?

```
int newVal=-1;
con.setAutoCommit(false);
PreparedStatement statement = con.prepareStatement("UPDATE atable SET val=val+1 WHERE id=?");
statement.setInt(1, id);
int result = statement.executeUpdate();
if (result != 1) {
    throw new SQLException("Nothing updated");
} else {
    statement = con.prepareStatement("SELECT val FROM atable WHERE id=?");
    statement.setInt(1, id);
    ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery();
    if (resultSet.next()) {
        newVal =  resultSet.getInt("val");
    }
}
statement.close();
con.commit();
con.setAutoCommit(true);
```

Thanks.

Comment: Don't forget to close your ResultSet!

Comment: If using JDK 7 you can use the [try with resources statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) and save yourself from the trouble of closing objects.

Comment: You did not close the first statement.

Comment: I am not sure why you are doing this, but there must be a more efficient way to maintain counters.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey probably is not the best way of doing it hoping someone has a better solution.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assuming you use some form of data source, you may configure there if you want transactionality and the isolation level. But to be explicit:

```
try(Connection con = ds.getConnection()){
   con.setTransactionIsolation(Connection.TRANSACTION_SERIALIZABLE);
   con.setAutoCommit(false);
   //...
} catch(SQLException sqle) {
   throw new MyModelException(e)
}
```

Now, you could trigger pesimistic locking by updating a version (or timestamp) field in your table. This will trigger a lock in the database (most likely at the record level):

```
try(PreparedStatement pStm = con.prepareStatement("update atable set version=version+1")){
   pStm.executeUpdate();
}
```

At this point, if another user is trying to update the same record simultaneously, this connection will either wait or timeout, so you must be ready for both things. The record will not be unlocked until your transaction ends (commit or rollback).

Then, you can safely select and update whatever you want and be sure that nobody else is touching your record as you process your data. If anybody else tries they will be put on wait until you finish (or they will timeout depending on connection configuration).

Alternatively you could use optimistic locking. In this case you read your record, do modifications to it, but in the update you make sure nobody else has changed it since you read it by checking that the version/timestamp field is the same as the one you orginally read. In this case you must be prepared to retry a transaction (or abort it alltogether) if you realize you have stale/outdated data.

i.e. `update atable set afield=? where id=? and version=1`

If the number of rows affected is 0, then you know that is probable that the record was updated between your read and your update and the record is no longer in version 1.

Comment: i actually ran my previous code using multiple threads in java, each thread updated then selected the updated value and printed it out each thread doing this simultaneously 5 times, each thread seems to print out a new value, none have printed duplicates,seems to work fine with the isolation level being set at read committed. Cant find a fault with this what do you think?

Answer (score 3):

Setting `autocommit=false` on your connection will *not* prevent other connections/threads from changing the row in the database! It will only disable automatic commits after each JDBC operation on that specific connection.

You will need to lock the row, eg. with `select ... for update` to prevent other transactions against the row, and also you will need to do your selects and updates within a single transaction.

Cheers,

Comment: Not to mention transaction isolation levels (which may play an important role in determining the visibility of changes as well)